# How to get the Button click count (which I have in UI )in backend spring boot code?

Tags: java, html, angular, spring-boot

I will get the button click count in angular code from the UI. I want to make use of this count in backend code which is basically a spring boot application.

How I can get that?

Here is the code:

Spring Boot Application:

metadata.add(PiiKeyValue.builder().key("Button Count").value(button_count).build());

Here button_count value I want to get from the UI.

Thanks in advance.

Shall I make use of RequestParam?

Comment: You need to use an Angular Service to send the data and a Spring Boot REST Controller to receive the data. If you want to use the value in a later time, you have to store it in a database.

Comment: I don't want to store in DB. I just want to get the click count in backend.

Comment: You need to update the question and explain what is your goal exactly.

Comment: The goal is simple. I just want to get the button_count value in the Back-end code.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is, it is just another variable / parameter, and would be propagated to the server-side with an http call like any other parameter. Which http method you use is up to your liking and considerations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How to propagate is the question mark here. I have the {{button_count}} in angular. I want to make use of that in Backend code which is basically a spring boot application.

Comment: He just told you to make http call to backend. Send the button count as a post call. here is the [reference](https://angular.io/guide/http) on how to do http calls.